# How to wait for parent process to send data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to using forks and I was wondering
if there is a way to wait for the parent process to send data to the child process?

maybe something like this

index.js:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

var child = fork(__dirname + '/index 2.js');

child.on('message', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

async function out(){

    child.send(50);

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000)); //sleeps for 3000ms

    child.send(30);
}

out();
```

index2.js:

```
let a=0;

function wait_and_listen(){ 
   let temp_data;
   process.on('message',(data)=>{temp_data=data});
   return temp_data;
}

a+=wait_and_listen();

a-=wait_and_listen();

process.send(a);
process.exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use promise in your child script to await for the parent to send data

not sure but maybe something like this:

```
let a = 0;

async function wait_and_listen() {

   return await new Promise((resolve) =>{
      process.on('message', (data) => { resolve(data); });
   });
}

(async()=>{

   a += await wait_and_listen();

   a -= await wait_and_listen();

   process.send(a);
   process.exit();
})();
```

**Edit:**
according to OP the above solution creates multiple listeners so in order to avoid that use `.once` instead of `.on` like this:

```
let a = 0;

async function wait_and_listen() {

   return await new Promise((resolve) =>{
      process.once('message', (data) => { resolve(data); });
   });
}

(async()=>{

   a += await wait_and_listen();

   a -= await wait_and_listen();

   process.send(a);
   process.exit();
})();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I tried your solution and it works but it opens multiple listeners for process.on(), your approach is accurate but can you resolve the issue?

Comment: I edited the answer and tested it, hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

you just use the "process.on('message') once and count its' calls.

```
// variable to detect if its the first call
let nthcall = 0;

// variable to accumulate data
let a = 0;

// work functon to be called when data is received from the parent
function work(data) {
    nthcall++;

    // feel free to do wwhatever you like with your data depending on nthcall value
    a += data;

    if (nthcall == 1) {
        console.log('first time i got data', data);
        return;
    }

    if (nthcall == 4) {
        console.log('last time i got data', data);
        process.send(a);
        process.exit(0);
    }

    console.log('i got data', data);
}

process.on('message', work);
```

Comment: how does that wait for the parent function to send data and use that to modify existing data like in the example? was the essence of the example understandable or should I modify it?

Comment: i added two lines : a += data; and process.send(a). does it make it clearer ?

Comment: so you dislike my solution ?